# Writing to sys/class/net in linux

Tags: c, linux

I'm thinking of saving data in /sys/class/net from a C program.

Is this possible?

Is there a process explaining how to use this file system for writing?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: There's a [Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt) in the kernel source. (But I don't know anything about it myself sorry.)

Comment: sysfs is a virtual file system, you can't simply use it to store hello.txt (neither should you)

Comment: I don't wish to store a text file just some data in the format that sysfs expects.